# How to we get the last ID of School in laravel?

Tags: laravel

We have many form or page with smart wizard. The first form or page or form that opens. It is the school. After filling out the school form We get the school ID, for example`21`. Then save it and click next open form with `school_id` 21.

### How  to get value `school_id` in value hidden.

I am very involved / please help me.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $school = SchoolsList::find(id);
    if($request->ajax()) {
        $activity = new Activity();
        $activity->cluster_id = $request->cluster_id;
        $activity->group_id = $request->group_id;
        $activity->school_id = $school->id;
        $activity->save();

        return response()->json(['data_activity' => $request->all(), 'id' => $activity->id]);
    }
}
```

I get this error.

> Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id'

[Help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkbmO.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be like this

```
$school = SchoolsList::find($request->id);
```

Comment: I get this error ... `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: are you getting the id from $request?